# cannot use LOCALE flag with a str pattern

Tags: python-3.x, xlwt

```
import xlwt

wb = xlwt.Workbook()

sheet1 = wb.add_sheet('Sheet 1')

wb.save('self, example.xls')
```

I am trying to learn how to create xls, edit xls, or delete if neccesary on python. I had verymuch trouble on this because every tutorial online doesn't mentions that I should put xlwt before Workbook but I figure it out now. The problem is when I run this code I get an error wich it says "ValueError: cannot use LOCALE flag with a str pattern" I don't even know what that means... What is it about and how can I fix it?

Comment: I searched for 3 hours more and I think it's a package error. I was too blind to see this webpage https://github.com/kennethreitz/tablib/pull/263 but is this a solution I still don't know. If it's a solution I don't know how can I apply to that. Need help guys...

Comment: New version of xlwt available from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlwt

Comment: Are you running via behave?

Answer (score 3):

There is a known-issue with tablib and Python 3.6, looks like it will be solved in the next releases.

For now, I make it work just downgrading to python 3.5.2

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: New release of xlwt is available from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlwt

Comment: @JohnMachin I dont think that solves the issue..Still persisting with 3.6.1

Comment: There does not seem to be an error purely in table, as I get the same error when running behave tests from PyCharm, where Python 3.6.1 is used.

Comment: I have this error with Python 3.6.4 and behave 1.2.5.

Comment: If you are not tied to "xls" and are okay with "xlsx" , install openpyxl and use ExcelWriter(xls_path) from pandas and do  "~path/file.xlsx" (** xlsx being the extension**) , doesn't give a locale issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and i resolved it by changing my series to "str" data type. df.astype("str")
Also not sure why you are trying to save your file as "self, example.xls". Could you print the entire error as it was given.